# How can I grab the index with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```css
.tb button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to Connect Four!</h1>
  <p>The object of this game is to connect four of your chips in a row!</p>
  <p id="inp">:it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your blue chip.</p>
  <table class="tb" align="center">
    <thead>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </thead><br>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I want to make the function that returns the index of a clicked button with JQuery. 
In addition to that, I want to make use of the index later for other functions. 
For example, if I click the index number 0 button on Google Chrome, I want the function to return 0.
How can I make the function with JavaScript?
I am a beginner, therefore plain coding would be happy for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the `index()` function.

You can define a global variable, for instance `buttonIndex`, and when a button is pressed save the index value in that variable:

```
let buttonIndex;

$('button').click( function() {
    buttonIndex = $(this).index();
});
```

Now you can use `buttonIndex` in other functions as well. This is the solution if you want the index relative to all the buttons in your page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and great answer. I can understand this coding easily. I appreciate for you and all of who commented on this question <(_ _)>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).parent('th').index()` for get column index

and `$(this).closest('tr').index()` for row index

also should use `tr` instead `thead` tag

```
   $("button").click(function() {
    var col_index = $(this).parent('th').index();
    var row_index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(row_index + "-" + col_index);
});
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var col_index = $(this).parent('th').index();
    var row_index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(row_index + "-" + col_index);
});
```

```css
.tb button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to Connect Four!</h1>
  <p>The object of this game is to connect four of your chips in a row!</p>
  <p id="inp">:it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your blue chip.</p>
  <table class="tb" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" name="button"></button></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great advice!  This works really well on my coding. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the id to the button and then on click you can use that id

For eg

```
<table>
      <thead >
        <th><button id="0-0" type="button" name="button" ></button></th>
        <th><button id="0-1" type="button" name="button"></button></th>
        ...
      </thead><br>
      <thead >
        <th><button id="1-0" type="button" name="button"></button></th>
        <th><button id="1-1" type="button" name="button"></button></th>
        ...
      </thead><br>
...
</table>
```

Your Javascript Code will be

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Your proposed solution won't work. First, you have to select `this`, so instead use `$(this)`. Secondly, the `id` property refers to the html id, not the number of the element.

Comment: Yes, We can use that way as well, I have mentioned that one as the commented code. `alert($(this).attr('id'));`